# How to measure the performance of the mode-line?

Tags: mode-line, performance

Currently when making changes to the mode-line, I try to write efficient elisp,

However I don't *know* for sure if what I'm doing is in fact efficient.

How could I test the mode-line performance?

For example - redraw the mode-line in a loop and time that.

Comment: what are you displaying on your mode line?

Comment: Just ascii text - nothing special, it's just that I'm using `:eval` to run code, which could become slow.

Comment: Redisplay affects mode-line behavior and apparent performance. And `:eval` can take a hit when redisplay happens. You might be able to otherwise check performance hits that you impose by using `force-mode-line-update`, but my guess is that all bets are off, in this regard - because you don't control when or how often redisplay occurs. But perhaps someone more knowledgeable will have something better to offer.

Comment: Here is a link to a S.O. thread that uses a `measure-time` macro from the Emacs help mailing list:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23622296/emacs-timing-execution-of-function-calls-in-emacs-lisp  The link to the Emacs help mail list thread is:  https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2008-06/msg00087.html

Answer (score 1):

This interactive function times `format-mode-line`.

```el
(defmacro mode-line-benchmark-elapse-time (&rest forms)
  "Return the time in seconds elapsed for execution of FORMS."
  (declare (indent 0) (debug t))
  (let ((t1 (make-symbol "t1")))
    `
    (let (,t1)
      (setq ,t1 (current-time))
      ,@forms
      (float-time (time-since ,t1)))))

(defun mode-line-benchmark ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((value nil)
         (repetitions 10000)
         (wall-clock-time
          (mode-line-benchmark-elapse-time
            (dotimes (_ repetitions)
              (setq value (format-mode-line mode-line-format)))))
         (average-time (/ wall-clock-time repetitions)))
    (message
     "Time: %.10f per call, %.10f for %S calls: %S"
     average-time wall-clock-time repetitions value)))
```

This can be run manually with `M-x mode-line-benchmark`